# Flex callback stack

Tags: java, apache-flex, callback, stack

I have a Flex problem. I have a Java app and a Flex app that calls to a Java app method to get some data.

So in my Flex class I have a method that calls the Java app method, something like this:

```
ObjectThatInvokesJavaMethod.getDataFromJavaApp(param1, setData);
```

setData is where the Java app method returns the array with the info, the callback.

The problem is that this method (setData) goes to a stack or something like that and the rest of code is executed, but in 'the rest of the code I need the data requested from the Java app but the setData method is not executed until the rest finish... so Im operating with old and deprecated data. Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Is setData a result handler?  Or is it data you're sending to the Java app?  That type of object is 'ObjectThatInvokesJavaMethod'?  an HTTPService?  A RemoteObject?  Or a WebService object?  If you're trying to pass a Flex function to Java and have Java execute it; that is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

your callback handler, setData() should assign the value from server-side AND call "the rest of the code" or whatever that is. or, throw an event from setData to signal that the data is ready and "the rest of the code" can use it.